# How to exclude rows base on a value range ? Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of 9636 rows in which I want to exclude the zipcodes ('zip') that are not from PA (range 15001 to 19611). I try to do this but it seems that it deleted all the columns. i want to keep all the columns with zip codes within this range (range 15001 to 196110)

**Code**

```
pa_zip = (CSR_data['zip'] >= 15001 ) & (CSR_data['zip']<= 19611)
pa_zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pa_zip = CSR_data[(CSR_data['zip'] >= 15001 ) & (CSR_data['zip']<= 19611)]
pa_zip
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer solves the question?

Comment: I assumed his dataset type is pandas dataframe object. So my answer is pandas filtering to solve the problem.Sorry if I am wrong